# Converter uma Session em Boolean - asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho no meu sistema uma Session que guarda uma informação “S” ou “N”

```
Session["Administrador"] = retorno.ADMINISTRADOR;
```

No layout eu quero fazer a conversão dela para boolean

```
@{
    bool administrador = bool.Parse(Session["Administrador"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente desta forma:

```
@{
    bool administrador = Session["Administrador"].ToString() == "S";
}
```

ou

```
@{
    bool administrador = Session["Administrador"].Equals("S");
}
```